# Cast to Generic Type in Generic Method

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I'm trying to write a method to return a list of all of a particular type  of control:

So I have something like the following method:

```vb
Private Function GetAllChildControls(Of T)(ByVal grid As DataGridItemCollection) 
                                           As List(Of T)
    Dim childControls As New List(Of T)
    For Each item As DataGridItem In grid 
        For Each tableCell As TableCell In item.Cells
            If tableCell.HasControls Then
                For Each tableCellControl As Control In tableCell.Controls
                    If tableCellControl.GetType Is GetType(T) Then

                        childControls.Add(DirectCast(tableCellControl, T))

                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return childControls
End Function
```

But this fails on the following code:

```vb
childControls.Add(DirectCast(tableCellControl, T))
```

I get the message:

> Cannot cast expression of type `System.Web.UI.Control` to type `T`.

How can I return a type specific list?

Comment: Mystery downvoter?  Any reasons?

Comment: Not me, but probably due to extensive nesting. This is considered bad practice by some, and is nearly impossible to maintain as the amount of code increases.

Comment: @Neolisk, Thanks for attempting an explanation.  If you can figure out how to LINQify that monster, I'm all ears, but I tried composing some linq queries and they seemed way less readable.  The whole point of this function is to wrap the nesting I need to do into a single method that I can call.  I really don't think it's that bad a practice.  And it's not the core component of my question anyway.

Comment: LINQ is bad, in terms of maintainability. I would favour plain old school code, even if you are going to have more of it. My quick attempt to improve code layout and readability: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gC1CmiDf#). Actually, even [this - pastebin #2](http://pastebin.com/DePKXbww).

Comment: My last attempt - only two levels of indentation. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/y27HJ5pC).

Comment: @Neolisk, [**0 Levels of Indentation!**](http://pastebin.com/RPWeDSyA).  Thanks for taking a look at my code.

Comment: Glad that I got you excited on that. I enjoy doing code optimizations at work and in my spare time. Well done! +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics can be ***anything***, so the compiler has no way of knowing that you only intend to call this method on types that inherit from `System.Web.UI.Control`.  You could, in fact, call the function with Type `Integer`, in which case the conversion will fail.

What you need to do is convince the compiler that you will only pass in certain types by using  [**Generic Constraints**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx#sectionToggle3).  Then you can only allow applicable types to call into the method.

All you need to do is modify your signature like this:

```vb
Private Function GetAllChildControlsInDataGrid(Of T As Control)(
                      ByVal grid As DataGridItemCollection) As List(Of T)
```